# Matrix structures in cvxopt

Tags: python, cvxopt

Here is the first example provided in the section **Semidefinite Programming** of the documentation of cvxopt
[text](https://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#semidefinite-programming)

[image: Problem]

Below is the code provided there:

```
from cvxopt import matrix, solvers

c = matrix([1.,-1.,1.])

G = [ matrix([[-7., -11., -11., 3.], 
    [ 7., -18., -18., 8.], 
    [-2.,  -8.,  -8., 1.]]) ]

G += [ matrix([[-21., -11.,   0., -11.,  10.,   8.,   0.,   8., 5.],
    [  0.,  10.,  16.,  10., -10., -10.,  16., -10., 3.],
    [ -5.,   2., -17.,   2.,  -6.,   8., -17.,  8., 6.]]) ]

h = [ matrix([[33., -9.], [-9., 26.]]) ]

h += [ matrix([[14., 9., 40.], [9., 91., 10.], [40., 10., 15.]]) ]

sol = solvers.sdp(c, Gs=G, hs=h)
```

Note that when defining `G`, the square matrices have been converted to column vectors. On the other hand, the square matrices keep their shapes when defining `h`. This code runs correctly and finds a solution.

I tried "matching the types" by converting the matrices in h to column vectors. However, it returned an error:

```
TypeError: hs[0] has size (4,1).  Expected size is (2,2).
```

I couldn't figure out why there needs to be a mismatch of the shapes of the matrices on the two sides of the condition `Gx <= h`.